# Possible to read an incomplete excel file?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd, pyexcel

I am currently using `openpyxl` to read the first 1000 rows of a very large (1GB) excel file. Is it possible to read excel data in openpyxl from an incomplete file? For example, if I only downloaded the first 10MB of the file instead of 1GB. Would there be any way to view the first 1000 of that (incomplete) file?

Currently I'm using:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('BigFile.xlsx', read_only=True)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
```

Though I'm open to using another library if it supports reading an incomplete excel file.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. An `.xlsx` is an xml file and they have a hierarchical and not necessarily linear structure. I think the simplest approach would be to download it once and convert it to a `.csv`, which can be split in the way you want.

Comment: @BoarGules for an incomplete xml file you could create a completed structure though with something like BeautifulSoup, right?

Comment: I saw your last post @DavidL, at this point why would this be better than using pandas?

Comment: @d_kennetz loading the above is instantaneous, whereas loading the above in pandas takes 6s.

Comment: certainly but you cannot partially load the file, and your comment above asked if you could recreate the excel using beautfulsoup, at which point would the overhead of that be worth the 6s it takes pandas to load

Comment: @DavidL Yes, in principle you could use BeautifulSoup to parse the file and make a subset of it. But I suspect that is a good deal easier said than done. And row 1000 might still be at the very end of the file.

Comment: @BoarGules also I believe it's a zip file, right? In which case downloading the first 5MB or so would be quite problematic I suppose...

Comment: @DavidL Quite right, I'd forgotten that. The data you want would be in `xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml` and you would have to extract that first.

Answer (score 0):

OOXML files are zip archives and, unlike gzip files, cannot really be streamed, ie. unpacked while still being transmitted. So, no, you cannot start reading the file while still downloading it.